# Navigator geolocation watchPosition and long running script(due to this browser crashed) in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, navigator

Am trying to get the current position using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` in a click event, it works fine on all browsers expect IE 11, In IE(first time working fine) it was returning error message in the second time if you trigger the click event. so as I got one solution from SO, based on it I have used `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` to check the position on some time interval.

```
var isPosistionDisplayed = false;


function findGeolocation() {
        var options = {
             enableHighAccuracy: true,
             timeout: 5000,
             maximumAge: 0
        },

            watchId = null,
            isIE = document.documentMode;

        if (typeof navigator.geolocation === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }

        if(isPosistionDisplayed && isIE) {
            watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
                _findForLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, STARTPAGE, _displayLocation);
                navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
                watchId = null;
                isPositionDisplayed = false;
                }, function() {
                _error();
            }, options);
        } else {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                _findForLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, STARTPAGE, _displayLocation);
                isPositionDisplayed = true;
            }, function() {
                _error();
            });
        }
    }
```

As per the above function it is a callback of an click event, so for the first click it will use the `getCurrentPosition` and second click if it is IE am setting watch it is continuously looping without clearing so browser got crashed. Is there anything am missing.?

Comment: `so for the first click it will use the getCurrentPosition` - no - it will ALWAYS use `getCurrentPosition` because every time `findGeolocation` is called, it executes `var isPosistionDisplayed = false` on line 7 - `watchPosition` will never get called with the code you've shown

Comment: @Jaromanda I have set isPositiondisplayed true in the success of getCurrentPosition

Comment: so what? next time you call `findGeolocation` it's not the same variable anyway (vars declared inside a function don't remember their state between calls to that function), and you set it to false on line 7  anyway - as I've already stated

Comment: Sorry that one is a global variable now I have edited my question, the second time it is going inside the watch but it is not ending.. :(

Comment: by `not ending` are you saying that `_findForLocation` is *continuously* being called? can you see any *useful* debugging information in the **developer** tools console?